Git Hub: how to update .yml scripts to include MSVC141
We are running a project on VS2019. it worked fine until last 2 months. suddenly it is raining exception SymbolScanner_Sharing\stdafx.h(22,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'atlbase.h': No such file or directory. which are irrelevant to the code changes I have done. Upon investigation I could see that the reason could be missing MSVC141. we use .yml scripts to define github actions. Can some one help me update the script to include MSVC141 toolset.
Sample yml script is as below:
name: Pull request - Windows

on:
  pull_request:
    paths-ignore:
    - 'Engine/Engine.Android/**'
    - 'Mobile/**'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-2022

    defaults:
      run:
        shell: pwsh

    env:
      DEFAULT_VERSION: v17.4.500
      SolutionDir: ${{ github.workspace }}\

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.RS_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        submodules: true
        
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v4
      with:
        distribution: 'temurin' # See 'Supported distributions' for available options
        java-version: '11'

    - name: Setup msbuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1

    # - name: Install WiX Toolset Extension
    #   run: |
    #     Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" -ArgumentList "/q /a Build\wix-toolset.vsix" -Wait

    - name: Setup NuGet sources
      uses: extenda/actions/setup-nuget-sources@v0
      with:
        config-file: NuGet.Config
        sources: |
          [{
            "name": "Nexus",
            "source": "https://repo.extendaretail.com/repository/nuget-hosted/",
            "username": "${{ secrets.NEXUS_USERNAME }}",
            "password": "${{ secrets.NEXUS_PASSWORD }}",
            "apikey": "${{ secrets.NUGET_API_KEY }}"
          }]

    - name: Restore NuGet packages
      run: nuget restore POS.sln

    - name: Determine version
      id: ver
      run: .\Build\determine-version.ps1

    - name: Update assemblies
      run: .\Build\update-assemblies.ps1 ${{ steps.ver.outputs.version }} ${{ steps.ver.outputs.full-version }}

    - name: Generate database template
      run: |
        .\Common\Database\AppVeyor\gen-databases.ps1 Common\Database abcDb
        Copy-Item abcDb\Template.db -Destination Common\Database

    - name: Build solution
      run: msbuild POS.sln @Build\WindowsBuildParams.rsp

    - name: Build installation packages
      run: |
        . Build\exit-on-failure.ps1
        msbuild Installation\Installation.sln @Build\WindowsBuildParams.rsp -p:BuildNumber=${{ steps.ver.outputs.full-version }}
        ExitOnFailure
        Get-ChildItem Installation\Bin\Release
        Rename-Item -Path Installation\Bin\Release\abc.msi -NewName abc-v${{ steps.ver.outputs.full-version }}.msi
        Rename-Item -Path Installation\Bin\Release\abc.exe -NewName abc-v${{ steps.ver.outputs.full-version }}.exe
        Rename-Item -Path Installation\Bin\Release\VRRSSurfaceComponentsEditor.msi -NewName SurfaceComponentsEditor-v${{ steps.ver.outputs.full-version }}.msi

    - name: Generate customization package
      run: .\Common\Database\AppVeyor\gen-customization-zip.ps1 Common\Database ${{ steps.ver.outputs.full-version }}

    - name: Save abcInstaller
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: abcInstaller-v${{ steps.ver.outputs.full-version }}
        path: Installation\Bin\Release\abc-*.msi

    - name: Save abcSetup
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: abcSetup-v${{ steps.ver.outputs.full-version }}
        path: Installation\Bin\Release\abc-*.exe

    - name: Save Database
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: Database-v${{ steps.ver.outputs.full-version }}
        path: Common\Database\CustomizationTemplate\*

I need a resolution to update the .yml script t get updated with MSVC141

Note: Pick tags with care. The C++ programmers monitoring the C++ tag for interesting C++ problems to solve likely aren't interested in problems with a git repository storing C++ stuff.

Are you saying that the GitHub build environment is missing msvc141, or that your MSBuild scripts specify a different toolchain?

You can use the vs_installer command to install the missing components for your toolchain; see the documentation for a list. See also this worked example
